# Button click not working when text area has content and keyboard is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I don't know how to properly ask this question. I've Googled a lot but have no clue on what's going on.

I have an HTML form in a responsive page with a textarea and an input button.
Opening the page in Chrome Mobile when textarea has text and the keyboard is opened if I click the button, the click event is not fired.
I have to hide the keyboard then click the button.
That way works ok.

I'm lost since HTML / CSS / JavaScript is not my strong skill...

Here is some of the code:

```
<footer id="footer">
            <div class="inner">

                <h3>Get in touch</h3>

                <form action="#" method="post">

                    <div class="field half first">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field half">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><input id="send" value="Send Message" class="button alt" type="button"></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>                 

            </div>
        </footer>
```

This is the Javascript part, simple as that:

```
$("#send").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log(new Date());
});
```

P.s.: Jquery handles the button click.

Comment: You should give us some code to help you

Comment: @Ivan Throw some code over there. That can enlight a little bit?

Comment: is the footer tag generated dynamically? can you try to anchor the event to body instead? `$("body").on("click","#send", function (e) {
    console.log(new Date());
});`

Comment: @threeFatCat No, the footer is not dynamic. I'll try your suggestion e get back with a feedback.

Comment: in addition, is the javascript code that you posted is wrapped with document.ready in the actual code?

Comment: @threeFatCat Not, it's not. The script tags are in the end of document. Should I wrap it?

Comment: Have you come across the same behavior on other sites that have textareas?

Comment: @jmcgriz No, first time.

Comment: What if you do `$("form").on("submit", function () {
    alert(new Date());
});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 $("#send").on("click touchstart", function (e) {
     console.log(new Date());
 });
```

Comment: I had to remove the "click" leaving only "touchstart". Otherwise the event fire twice. That way worked.